# What is the term used to create a mesh with less vertices using shrinkwrap?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I used to know this term but I haven't thought about it in over a year, so I completely forgot about what it's called. The term refers to using the shrink-wrap modifier to maker a new mesh over an old one to change the amount of vertices when the old one has too many?

Comment: retopology? I'm not sure shrinkwrap is always the best way to retopologize though

Comment: Ya thats it. Is there a better way to retopology?

Comment: @Bpbutcher please ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to *Retopology*. And yes, in Blender the *Shrinkwrap* modifier is commonly used in combination with other modifiers to perform retopology.